# Store Stream in cache

Tags: c#, caching

I'd like to cache the response I get from a HttpWebRequest. I need both the ResponseStream and the headers. Using `HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpCacheAgeControl.MaxAge, TimeSpan.FromDays(1))` when creating the request doesn't seem to work (IsFromCache is never true for some reason), and I'm a bit scared of manually caching the entire HttpWebResponse since it's containing a stream of gzipped data, and I have a bad feeling about storing streams in the ASP.NET cache.

The response is mapped to an object like this (simplified):

```
public readonly Stream Response;
public readonly string Etag;

private MyObject(Stream response, string etag)
{
    this.Response = response;
    this.Etag = etag;
}
```

Since the object also contains the response stream I face the same issue here.

How do I cache this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `Stream` is a *pipe*, not a *bucket*. If you need to store it, you must first get the actual contents. For example, you could read it all into a `byte[]`. For example:

```
using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    response.CopyTo(ms);
    byte[] payload = ms.ToArray();
}
```

You can store the `byte[]` trivially. Then if you want a `Stream` later, you can use `new MemoryStream(payload)`.

Comment: +1 I was going to type up the exact same thing, you may want to include how to copy the [WebHeaderCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.WebHeaderCollection%20.aspx) that `HttpWebRequest.Headers` points to too. Also, his "Container" structure could just hold the memory stream itself, no need to copy to an array.

Answer (score 2):

Can you create a custom class that contains a byte array for storing the data and another field with HttpWebRequest.Headers for the headers?  Then cache that.